# Is it possible to deploy MS SQL scripts using Ansible?

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, ansible, continuous-deployment

We are currently using SqlPackage.exe to create dacpac and deploy the dacpac. Is it possible to deploy the dacpac/sql code using Ansible?

Comment: I didn't find any in built module for this ? let others confirm. Meanwhile have you researched ansible docs for this ?

Comment: It works with Jenkins, which simply runs the dacpac deployment utility, so I expect it would also work with Ansible in a similar fashion.

Comment: You can use win_command or win_shell.

Comment: If it works with Jenkins, you can trigger the Jenkins job from ansible.

Comment: To work with jenkins you might need to register that node as slaves and use it. Ansible as per my knowledge doesn't have `dacpac` but I will search more. Also win_command or win_shell would be best way to deploy it OR write your own custom module.